# UIView backed by CATiledLayer in UIScrollView doesn't scroll initially

Tags: uiscrollview, scroll, cgcontext, zooming, catiledlayer

I'm adding a CATiledLayer backed UIView in UIScrollView.

When the view is first loaded, I'm trying to fit the UIView, by setting the zoomScale of UIScrollView - this fits the UIView and the layered contents.

I'm having a method to fetch the tiles of image and I'm rendering them in drawLayer:inContext:

Now even if the contentsize of scrollview/frame of CATiledLayer view is greater than UIScrollView, it doesn't scroll initially.

The moment I try to zoom by pinching the screen, I'm able to scroll perfectly.

I can't scale the CGContext in drawLayer:inContext, since the context I receive is of a tile and not whole image and I have 20 tiles which make up my image.

Answer (score 1):

At the end of the initWithFrame of the PDFScrollView i added the line:-

```
self.zoomScale = 1.0;
```

This worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

The code is pretty much doing the same stuff as apple example

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/ZoomingPDFViewer/Introduction/Intro.html%23//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40010281-Intro-DontLinkElementID_2

which also doesnt scroll on loading